# Excel VBA Application.Interaction

Tags: vba, excel

I have some macro code that runs in my BeforeSave event and before it runs I am using the following line.

```
Application.Interactive = False
```

When saving the file normally everything works fine. If I select multiple tabs via ctrl/click and try to save I get an error which reads.

```
Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Interactive' of object '_Application' failed
```

It seems to me that the Interactive property is not available to set when you have multiple sheets selected. The reason I want to select several sheets and not the entire document is I am doing a save as and selecting PDF.

Any ideas why this would not work or what could be use in place of Application.Interactive?

Comment: Does seem to be a bug, or is on-purpose due to some limitation of having multiple sheets selected.  Do you really need `Interactive` ?  I've never used it in years of Excel VBA.

Comment: Ditto what Tim said.  And I assume `Interaction` is a typo in the question, which is not in your code.

Comment: Yes, `Application.Interactive` is not settable if many sheets are selected. To find workarounds, could you state what is precisely the aim of disabling interactive mode?

Comment: `Application.Interactive`'s main use seems to be to prevent the user from interfering with `Activate`, `Select`, `Active*` and company.  I suspect you can remove it entirely if you fix that underlying issue in your code. See [Avoid using SELECT or ACTIVATE](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201701060115559008704).

Comment: I just want to make sure that the end user makes no changes to the workbook during the save routine. I was under the impression I needed to set Interactive to false to accomplish that.